# Sentiment analysis using python textblob on a excel file data

Tags: python, excel, pandas, sentiment-analysis, textblob

[image]I have a problem where , I need to calculate sentiment analysis of two columns present in the excel file and after calculation of polarity of those two columns, I need to update those polarity values in two other columns which are already present in the same excel input file. Any how I have achieved by calculating polarity of single text sentence . Need suggestions to calculate polarity of entire column present in the excel file.
I am using pandas for excel processing.

```
from textblob import TextBlob
import pandas as pd
Input_file='filepath'
df = pd.read_excel(Input_file, 
sheet_name='Sheet1')
col1 = pd['video_title'].tolist()
# col2 = pd['description'].tolist()
blob = TextBlob(col1)
# blob1 = Texxtblob(col2)
polarity_score = blob.sentiment.polarity
polarity_rounded = round(polarity_score, 6)
print(polarity_rounded)
```

As i posted in the above image, here i need to replace the values 'None' in the column 'title_sentiment' to the calculated polarity values. Likewise, i have to update the 'description_sentiment' column to the calculated polarity values.

Desired output:
[image]

Comment: Could you give an example input/output of your desired results?  We can probably black-box the sentiment part of this as just some function that gives a number and help you get the results in the form you're looking for.

Comment: [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qmKSm.png
As i posted in the above image, i need to replace the values 'None' in the column 'title_sentiment' to the calculated polarity values. Likewise, i have to update the 'description_sentiment' column to the calculated polarity values like 0.1, 0, 0.23 etc.

Comment: @user1717828 desired output would like  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/EWRFu.png

Answer (score 1):

Let's blackbox your sentiment analysis stuff and reduce your problem to

> I have a dataframe with a text column that I want to apply a function to, and the store the result as a new numeric column in the correct row.

Stealing [this person's example dataframe](https://queirozf.com/entries/pandas-dataframe-examples-duplicated-data) with a text column to get started:

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd 
    ...:  
    ...: df = pd.DataFrame({ 
    ...:     'title': ['foo','bar','baz','baz','foo','bar'], 
    ...:     'contents':[ 
    ...:         'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.', 
    ...:         'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.', 
    ...:         'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.', 
    ...:         'Consectetur adipiscing elit.', 
    ...:         'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.', 
    ...:         'Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.' 
    ...:     ], 
    ...:     'year':[2010,2011,2000,2005,2010,2011] 
    ...: }) 
    ...:  
    ...: df                                                                                                                                                   
Out[1]: 
  title                      contents  year
0   foo   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  2010
1   bar   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  2011
2   baz   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  2000
3   baz  Consectetur adipiscing elit.  2005
4   foo   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  2010
5   bar   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  2011
```

Now we want to define a function to apply to "contents" and store the result in a new column.  For this, we can use `pd.Series.apply()`:

```
In [2]: def sentiment_function(text): 
    ...:     # Put all your fancy sentiment stuff here; I will just use `len` as a dummy function. 
    ...:     return len(text) 
    ...:      
    ...: df['sentiment_score'] = df['contents'].apply(sentiment_function) 
    ...: df                                                                                                                                                   
Out[2]: 
  title                      contents  year  sentiment_score
0   foo   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  2010               27
1   bar   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  2011               27
2   baz   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  2000               27
3   baz  Consectetur adipiscing elit.  2005               28
4   foo   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  2010               27
5   bar   Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.  2011               27
```

You can do this for your both of your columns, `title_sentiment` and `description_sentiment`.

Comment: Thanks @user1717828, after couple of amendments to my code along with your code snippets, I had achieved the intended output.